# All Linux OS on HP Notebook misbehaving

Tags: firmware

My Hp Notebook is about 2.5 years old.  On it I have Ubuntu, Kali, and Debian (Stretch) alongside windows.

Last night Ubuntu started to misbehave.  I could use the touch pad or the mouse to open programs, but once open I can't click on any thing or do anything because it just won't select.

I tried Kali and Debian, and it was the same sort of thing with them too, with an assortment of other problems.  Even live USB drives are misbehaving.

I tried a BIOS recovery which made no difference.  Windows doesn't appear to be as affected.  Once Windows recovered from the punishment of not being shutdown properly, many times over the last few years (thank you so much HP firmware), the only symptom it showed was, when scrolling  down a web page, when clicking on something inside the page it would sling shot to the top of the page again.

Ubuntu is the OS that I use on a daily basis.  Really ?  Even live USB Drives ??  The firmware forces me to select the UEFI file for the Linux operating systems every time. I'm not sure if I used the right tag.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your question about the firmware?

Comment: I couldnt't really decide on what tag was applicable, because I've never seen this before and have no idea as to what is happening.  I, and my tech guy thought, possibly firmware.  Someone please tell me it's the hardware, so I can drop it from a high place, knowing there is no wastage, and I can say goodbye to HP and MS for good.  I'll be quite happy with Raspbian and my pi, I was just getting the last out of the hardware and I did qutie like 16.04.

Comment: Please feel free to edit the title and tags, if there is a solution to this situation, for the betterment of the knowledge base.